# Can context sensitive inference be "pushed up" chained method invocations?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I'm trying to build a Zod-ish API, but with type inference of values instead of the `z.string()`-is-definitely a string, i.e. I want to do something like:

```js
// Create a Zod-style fluent DSL for building config
const c = {
  value<V>(): ValueConfig<V> {
    return null!;
  },
};

type Config<T> = { [P in keyof T]: ValueConfig<T[P]> };

function config<T>(object: Config<T>): void {}

// Allow fluent methods
interface ValueConfig<V> {
  req(): ValueConfig<V>;
  readOnly(): ValueConfig<V>;
  validate(fn: (value: V) => boolean): ValueConfig<V>;
}

// A pojo
type Author = { name: string; address: string; city: string };

// Try and configure the author
config<Author>({
  // correctly inferred as c.value<string> --> ValueConfig<string>
  name: c.value(),
  // inferred only as c.value<unknown> --> ValueConfig<unknown>
  address: c.value().req(),
  // compile error, v is implicitly typed as any
  city: c.value().validate((v) => v.length > 0),
});
```

The issue is that context-sensitive inference works for "just one method call", i.e. `name: c.value()` is inferred as `ValueConfig<string>`, but once I try chaining method calls, i.e. `address: c.value().req()` or `city: c.value().validate(...)`, the `string`-ness doesn't get pushed up into the originating `c.value()` to then flow into the `.req()`.

I assume this is just a limitation of context sensitive inference? Are there any alternative approaches to achieving a similar API?

Comment: This is almost certainly a limitation of context sensitive inference; maybe [ms/TS#47599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599) is the most appropriate github issue about it, but there will always be limitations like this.  As for alternative approaches I think I'd need to see more of a [mre] of the functionality needed (unless you think this question needs knowledge of zod to answer, in which case you should tag it as such).  Right now the types are so general that you can move generics around like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDA38m) and it "works".  How do you want to proceed?

Comment: Hi @jcalz! I had seen 47599 and that makes sense, maybe I'll add my use case there... per an example, my library's API currently requires typing out ADTs / object literals like `{ type: "value" | "list" | ... `}, and imo Zod-style fluent APIs have become popular, so I'm trying to mimic that. If you're curious:

https://github.com/homebound-team/form-state/pull/90/files#diff-f988d20e3370db072b9a307a7cfd4c129ed8d5ef7772da194bd0114b3c578bd7L116

I'd like `f.config<AuthorInput>` to dictate the `f.value()` type; Zod doesn't rely on inference b/c their `z.string()` is already correctly typed.

Comment: I'm not particularly inclined to look at external code unless it fits in a single file in my IDE.  Could you provide a self-contained [mre] that motivates the generics in the question itself?  If, at runtime, `c.value()` is a valid `ValueConfig<V>` for all possible `V`, then `ValueConfig<V>` should probably not be generic at all.  But without something I can easily poke at I won't speculate further.

Comment: Totally get not looking at external code, just wasn't sure how to give more context--but I did put slightly more context in [TS#47599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599#issuecomment-1712696120) i.e. it adds a `ValueConfig.validate` method that shows the types need to match for the lambda to type-check (as, you're right, in the SO question the generic-ness of ValueConfig doesn't seem necessary--I'll try to edit the SO question to show that). 

Fwiw happy to give you the answer here, i.e. "yes this is a limitation of context sensitive inference". Thanks!